# Why do scientists get irate when mystical interpretations of physics are brought up?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, consciousness, psychology

Science typically refers people to Philosophy when such subjects are brought up.  But yet they know that there are profound **metaphysical** implications of the physics of the last century, *and* since the spiritual interpretations don't *conflict* with the science, it doesn't quite seem in harmony with their otherwise neutral and inquisitive state of mind.

Science, after all, is *supposed* to be about Truth -- regardless of whether it conforms to any popular model.  And their model of reality would make us all automatons, would it not, if governed only by the laws of physics?

Comment: who is they? do you mean philosophy _in general?_ physicists in general?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a real, constructive question. I understand the need to blow off steam if the physics.SE folk haven't been very accepting of your participation, but this question isn't really within the realm of philosophy. It's psychology at best, but it would be closed there as well because it makes a bold, unsupported claim without any real explanation.

Comment: @stoicfury:It's a good question. I don't think it should have been closed. In this review of Jim Holts book, [why does the world exist](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/2012/nov/08/what-can-you-really-know/?pagination=false). Freeman Dyson, a physicist concludes that 'Modern departments of philosophy have no place for the mystical.' Would he have concluded the same for Physics? It obviously has a role in his own life.

Comment: Presumably, Wittgenstein read out Tagores mystical poetry to the Vienna Circle for the same reason.(TLP 6.522 reads: “There is indeed the inexpressible. This shows itself; it is the mystical.”)

Comment: And Grothendieck, after remaking the field of Algebraic Geometry in his own image, departed for mystical tranquillity at the age of 40; he wrote on the art of problem-solving: '*A different image came to me a few weeks ago. The unknown thing to be known appeared to me as some stretch of earth of hard marl, resisting penetration…the sea advances insensibly in silence, nothing seems to happen, nothing moves, the water is so far off you hardly hear it…yet it finally surrounds the resistant substance.'*

Comment: Not constructive? It's the most constructive question I've seen for a while and a fascinating one so I'd vote to re-open. It is a fine philosophical question that deserves an answer. I can easily imagine Erwin Schrodinger asklng it. Surely as philosophers we should all know the answer to it.

Comment: It appears that this question has been closed by one person. If it was five then I'd  accept the verdict but as things are I'd like to ask why it is closed. Perhaps it would be better if it asked what objections scientists make to 'mystical interpretations' such as Schrodinger's, but it seems a clear enough question as it stands. If the mods all agree with closing it then I'll go away, but do they?    .

Comment: Actually science is not about finding Truth; its about finding truth.

Comment: To be honest that post just sounds like nonsense. I can't even try to convert it into a coherent idea. If you told me reality has 8 dimsions and that concept is not inconsistent with reality and I can use it to make accurate predictions, I would have no problem.

Comment: In re your recent edit to add the final sentence *And their model of reality would make us all automatons...*. It may or may not; that is immaterial insofar as the scientific endeavor is concerned. If we are all automata, then science wants to reveal that fact to us; if we are not, then science wants to reveal that fact to us. Science is not responsible for the facts, its duty is to make the facts available to us.  *Argumentum ad consequentiam* and so forth.

Comment: @DanBron:  "If we are all automata, then science wants to reveal that fact to us."  Wherefrom this "want"?

Comment: @cell:  The post is in reference to the science community's response to the film "What the #%@#% do we know?".

Comment: @Marxos It’s metaphorical, anthropomorphization. Also, don’t think I’ve ever gotten a reply ~4 years after the fact.

Answer (score 8):

[Richard Feynman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYPapE-3FRw) summarized modern science with this statement:

> In general we look for a new law by the following process. First we
>   guess it. Then we compute the consequences of the guess to see what
>   would be implied if this law that we guessed is right. Then we compare
>   the result of the computation to nature, with experiment or
>   experience, compare it directly with observation, to see if it works.
>   **If it disagrees with experiment it is wrong. In that simple statement
>   is the key to science.** It does not make any difference how beautiful
>   your guess is. It does not make any difference how smart you are, who
>   made the guess, or what his name is – if it disagrees with experiment
>   it is wrong. That is all there is to it.

Experimentation is the foundation of all modern science (particularly physics).  It is the key difference that has allowed tremendous progress in science over the past few centuries compared to, eg, classical Greece.  There were plenty of very intelligent people thinking about the physical world, but without that key mindset that experimentation must trump everything else, the progress was hindered.

By their nature, spiritual things are supernatural; therefore, they are outside the realm of experimentation.  For this reason, there is no place in modern science for spiritual explanations.

Comment: Yes, I like Feynmann's stance, but I would add that your statement "[spiritual things] are outside the realm of experimentation" is only true in an _a posteriori_ sense, after these boundaries have been established --  a consequence of man's historical quest of knowledge not a source of science.

Comment: On Feynmans simple prescription, the greeks that came up with atomic theory over 2 millenia ago, would have to be dismissed as being 'not even testable'. String theory is currently not seriously testable, and it probably won't be for some time, and you have a lot of serious physicists working on it. There is a large element of speculation in physics which gets covered up because of its reputation as a hard science. Quite a number of physicists have been into eastern mysticism - see Bohm for instance. Or Weil, but he was mathematician. I don't know why physicists get het up about myticism

Comment: maybe they're not as rational as they think they are.

Comment: Mysticism is entirely and completely grounded in experimentation. I cannot imagine why anyone would believe otherwise.

Comment: If mysticism is amenable to experimentation, then it falls within the purview of the scientific method, and can be disproven (or not).  At that point, it's no longer mysticism, but 'physics' or 'biology'.

Comment: @PeterJ The results of a mystic experiment are not normally visible to anyone but the mystic.  If they are reproducible by sufficiently many people, we can treat them scientifically.  Feynman doubtless meant "experiment" as something that can be objectively verified.  If you can levitate due to a mystical practice, that's verifiable.  If you can see the face of God, that isn't.

Comment: @DavidThornley - It is not experimentation that distinguishes natural science. Yoga is called a science because it relies on experimentation,.What distinguished physics from mysticism is its inability to study non-empirical reality, not its experimentation, If you want to know whether there is some truth in the Perennial philosophy further to what may be established by logic and analysis then experimentation would be the only way.

Comment: @PeterJ One thing that distinguishes physics from mysticism is success.  After centuries of having mystics around, the world still abounds with unenlightened people.  Far more people have had their lives improved by science than mysticism.  I've had my own mystical experiences, and I'm reluctant to talk about them because I can't teach other people to have them or to know really what they are.  Scientific experiments aren't limited to individual scientists to make, observe, and interpret, and that's the big difference.

Comment: @DavidThornley - I find it difficult to grasp how a philosophy and practice that is still so popular after three thousand years and more can be called unsuccessful. But yes, making progress in mysticism as a student is tough compared to science. Of course its not an empirical science, but nothing Popper says prevents us calling Yoga a science. After all, consciousness studies is considered a science.these days.

Comment: @PeterJ Think falsiiability and replication.  A physicist can tell you how to construct apparatus and conduct an experiment.  If the apparatus is properly constructed and used, the result should be the same.  (If nobody else can replicate it, it's not science.)  If my samadhi doesn't do something Patanjali said it would, is my samadhi lacking or is the sutra wrong?  Can you examine my ability at samadhi independently to find what went wrong (much like they eventually found a loose cable in the neutrino speed experiment that found the buggers moving faster than light)?

Comment: @DavidThornley - Yes, I get all that. But the issue is not simple. Regardless of whether your practice is lacking or the sutra is wrong you are at least testing it, albeit not effectively. I feel it's matter of definition and have no strong view but know that many see the practice as a science. The Dalai Lama met Popper and yet considers Buddhism a science of mind. I feel he has a point but concede it; arguable,

Answer (score 2):

Why do we get angry about anything? We could say that many times it is because we have personal issues related to the event or subject in question.

In the case of physicists, that also may or may not apply.

But in my experience, even if the above is the case, it is usually justified. People tend to distort or misinterpret physics claims in order to fit their own beliefs. Specially with modern physics, that has a lot of out-of-the-ordinary consequences, many people take a superficial view and use that as an "explanation" for spiritual stances.

Ken Wilber has an audio conversation entitled ["Does Quantum Physics Prove God?"](http://www.kenwilber.com/blog/show/39) in which he says that it does not, and that those claims come from misunderstandings. The interesting thing is that Wilber himself is a "spiritualist" (whatever that may mean), but he says that that kind of mix of physics and spirituality is both bad physics and bad mysticism.

So when a physicist gets aggro about that, I would consider that it is because so many people has misused physics without really understanding it, simply trying to transfer some of physics knowledge's strength to the "spiritual".